# Can't dynamically set array initializer length

Tags: c#, arrays, object-initializers, collection-initializer

I am using C# to hook into the FedEx API and I'm a bit stumped on how to modify some existing code to meet my needs.  The snippet included is part of their canned code where they sample how to work with 1 commodity.  However, when my code runs I will have n commodities...and I'm unsure how to dynamically address this.

As an example, if I have 3 commodities, and I manually add 3 `new Commodity()` statements it will work fine.  However this needs to be dynamic.

```
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[3] { 
  new Commodity(), 
  new Commodity(), 
  new Commodity() 
};
```

Here is the start of the method, where the first line is what I need help with.  After that I think putting everything else in a loop based on array size should be fine.

```
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[1] { 
  new Commodity() 
};

request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].NumberOfPieces = "1";
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Description = "Books";
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].CountryOfManufacture = "US";
//
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight = new Weight();
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight.Value = 1.0M;
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight.Units = WeightUnits.LB;
```

If I simply do this, I get an error:

```
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[3] { 
  new Commodity() 
};
```

> "An array initializer of length 3 is expected"

Comment: Why not put `[]` i.e. `request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[] { new Commodity() };` and let system derive the actual size

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when I do this and run it through a loop for 3 commodities it works fine for array position 0.  When it gets to position 1 I get System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: do not *hardcode* indexes: `Commodities[1]` i.e. commodity **#2** will throw exception if you have just **1** commodity in the array. What is your loop, then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't have to mention `1` or `3` at all; put `[]` and let system compute the required length for you:

```
// Commodity[3] will be created
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[] { 
  new Commodity(), 
  new Commodity(), 
  new Commodity() 
};
```

Or

```
// Commodity[1] will be created
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[] { 
  new Commodity()
};
```

If you want to create an array of size `n`, you can try *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int n = 3;

request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = Enumerable
  .Range(0, n) 
  .Select(index => new Commodity())
  .ToArray();
```

Or even

```
int n = 3;

// 3 equivalent commodities
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = Enumerable
  .Range(0, n) 
  .Select(index => new Commodity() {
     NumberOfPieces = "1", 
     Description = "Books",
     CountryOfManufacture = "US",
     Weight = new Weight() {
       Value = 1.0M,
       Units = WeightUnits.LB
     }
   })
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Your first Linq example works like a champ, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitry Sir, covered almost everything in above answer... However, below section can also be written as followed section:

**Your original code**

```
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[1] { 
  new Commodity() 
};

request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].NumberOfPieces = "1";
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Description = "Books";
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].CountryOfManufacture = "US";
//
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight = new Weight();
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight.Value = 1.0M;
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities[0].Weight.Units = WeightUnits.LB;
```

It can be modified as below:

**Modified dynamic len array and property initialized code**

```
request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.Commodities = new Commodity[] { 
   new Commodity {
      NumberOfPieces = "1",
      Description = "Books",
      CountryOfManufacture = "US",
      Weight = new Weight{
            Value = 1.0M,
            Units = WeightUnits.LB
      },
      // add more properties... as per requirement
   },
   // add more objects... as per requirement
};
```